# Customizing configuration with Dependency Injection

Tags: design, dependency-injection, application-design

I'm designing a small application infrastructure library, aiming to simplify development of ASP.NET MVC based applications. Main goal is to enforce convention over configuration.

Hovewer, I still want to make some parts "configurable" by developpers.

I'm leaning towards the following design:

```
public interface IConfiguration
{
    SomeType SomeValue;
}

// this one won't get registered in container
protected class DefaultConfiguration : IConfiguration
{
    public SomeType SomeValue { get { return SomeType.Default; } }
}

// declared inside 3rd party library, will get registered in container
protected class CustomConfiguration : IConfiguration
{
    public SomeType SomeValue  { get { return SomeType.Custom; } }
}
```

And the "service" class :

```
public class Service
{
    private IConfiguration conf = new DefaultConfiguration();

    // optional dependency, if found, will be set to CustomConfiguration by DI container
    public IConfiguration Conf { get { return conf; } set { conf = value; } }

    public void Configure()
    {
        DoSomethingWith( Conf );
    }
}
```

There, the "configuration" part is clearly a dependency of the service class, but it this an "overuse" of DI ?

Comment: You may want to narrow it down to the individual items being configured instad of having a configuration class.

Answer (score 1):

Normally DI frameworks do something like `container.GetInstance<T>()` to get an instance of the type `T`. This doesn't require each new type to have a code change to your configuration class. Then you can set it up like `container.Configure(x => x.For<T>().Use(() => default(T)))` or whatever else makes sense.

Now where the power really starts to shine is when you have...

```
public class Service
{
  public Service(IConfigurationObject config)
  {
    _config = config;
  }
  readonly IConfigurationObject _config;
}
```

And the container automatically fills out your constructor with the dependency. I'd start out with understanding a container before digging into this too deeply yourself. http://structuremap.net/structuremap/QuickStart.htm is as good place to start as any other.